# Using ResourceQuery in sonar web client

Tags: sonarqube

How to find variance(in last 30 days) in metrics in sonar.
Previously i was using the api/resources/ url and ResourceQuery in sonar ws client api.Now it has been deprecated.

Comment: The deprecation notice for the web service tells you what to use instead. If that recommendation is inappropriate for your use, please [edit] your question to include why.

Comment: using this api /measures/search_history to find delta..thanks,